# Having contact with lover or fiance before marriage

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, relationships

In this new world we adopt many things which are prohibited in Islam. I want to ask that if a person daily contacts his lover or fiance so what does Islam says about this. We think that man and woman are going to marry each other so they know about each other. As  Islam is a true religion and Islam leads us in the right way in every stage of life, in the light of Islam is it **Haram** or **Halal** to contact fiance or lover  before marrying her or him.

Comment: There is no such thing as a fiance in Islam. Either you are married or you are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother, it is a very sensitive matter. Of course, we should not contact even with fiance. As Allah says in Holy Quran:

**Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do.**

Chapter Number 24: Verse Number 30

The same message repeated for women, as Allah says in the Holy Quran in following verses:

**And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment.**

Chapter Number 24: verse Number 31